# How to handle missing x-axis values when plotting multiple line charts using python-pptx

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-pptx

I am trying to plots multiple line charts on same graph using `python-pptx` module. Here is my data:

```
month   desc value
201911   a  1164
201912   a   971
202001   a  1125
202005   b  1549
202005   a  1038
202006   b  1244
202006   a  1475
202007   a   960
```

The `month` column can range from `201910 to 202008`.

I draw line charts for `a` and `b` desc colum values with `month on X axis`.

Here is the code:

```
chart_data = ChartData()
cat=list(data["month"].unique())
chart_data.categories = cat
data=data.sort_values(['month'], ascending=[True])
for i in list(data["desc"].unique()):
            
    
    chart_data.add_series(i,tuple(data[data['desc']==i]['value']))
    
    x, y, cx, cy = Inches(1), Inches(1), Inches(9), Inches(6)
    chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.LINE, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data).chart
```

As we can see for value of `a` in desc column and the values from `b` are different.

The plot gives wrong alignment of x axis and y-axis values.

[image]

The plot for `b` starts rom `201911`... However it should start from `202005`. How to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `None` as the value for any points you don't want to be plotted. I looks like your data retrieval simply *omits* missing data points. You need to get it so the categories sequence and the values sequence (for each series) are the same length and aligned by position.

Like:

```
categories = ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar")
series_values = (1, 2, 3)
```

If the value for Jan and Feb are missing, sending:

```
categories = ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar")
series_values = (3)
```

will give you a chart like the one in your example. What it needs to be is:

```
categories = ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar")
series_values = (None, None, 3)
```